# How to fix " java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java320 in java.library.path:

Tags: java, opencv, ubuntu, jar

I have installed Java 12 on Ubuntu 18.04. After that, I cannot use the opencv jar. It gives this output in the console.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no
>   opencv_java320 in java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib,
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni, /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu,
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu, /usr/lib/jni, /lib, /usr/lib]  at
>   java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2660)    at
>   java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:829)    at
>   java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1867)  at
>   nu.pattern.OpenCV$SharedLoader.(OpenCV.java:190)    at
>   nu.pattern.OpenCV$SharedLoader.(OpenCV.java:185)    at
>   nu.pattern.OpenCV$SharedLoader$Holder.(OpenCV.java:225)   at
>   nu.pattern.OpenCV$SharedLoader.getInstance(OpenCV.java:229)   at
>   nu.pattern.OpenCV.loadShared(OpenCV.java:179)     at
>   Hello.main(Hello.java:7)

yes, I have loaded the system library.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    nu.pattern.OpenCV.loadShared();           System.loadLibrary(org.opencv.core.Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
    }
```

Comment: You should put the `opencv_java320.so` file into `/usr/lib` folder. And then restart your IDE, and DONE!

Comment: @BahramdunAdil where do I get the .so file?

Comment: For windows, it will be present in the download package, but for Linux, you need to build OpenCV from source, then it will generate the `.so` file.